# Laravel multiple relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I am trying to get my head around some relationships between models in Laravel.

I would like to define the relationship between the following models:
User - the users
Campaign - a campaign
Call - a phone call
Lead - Lead/client
Sale - A sale
Appointment - A scheduled phone call.

This is the way the relationship should be:

A user can be assigned to many campaigns. 
A user can have many calls.
One user can have many appointments.
One call belongs to one user.
One call belongs to one campaign.
A campaign can have many calls.
A campaign can have many sales
A lead can be assigned to many campaigns. 
A lead can have many sales
One lead belongs to one user in one campaign.
One lead can have many calls
One sale belongs to one campaign
One sale belongs to one user
One appointments belongs to one lead.

I uncertain about how to setup the relationship. Its easy with the one-to-one or many-to-one. 
But what about this:
Call->User (one-to-one)
Call->Campaign (one-to-one)
Campaign->Call (one-to-many)
User->Call (one-to-many)

Hopefully I managed to explain it clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Read about aggregates in DDD

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading the [Laravel docs on relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) again.

Taking the Call/User relationship as an example, here's what you're looking at:

```
User  --------> Call
(one)           (many)
```

This is clearly a one to many relationship. And if you want to set up both sides of this relationship in terms of an Eloquent model, the relationships are this:

```
A User hasMany Calls

A Call belongsTo a User
```

These terms are taken directly from the documentation, in the section entitled *One To Many*.

So, in code...

**User Model**

```
public function Calls()
{
    $this->hasMany("Call");
}
```

(notice that I've made the method name plural - this is my own preference, since using `$user->Calls` will return a collection if items).

**Call Model**

```
public function User()
{
    $this->belongsTo("User");
}
```

Rather than taking the two sides of a relationship in isolation, as you seem to have done in your analysis, consider **both sides** of the relationship at the same time.

Comment: Hi @Kryten,

Thank you for your answer. Your answer is what I already got from the documentation.

Now we have a one-to-many relationship between User and Call. 
So now we need to make a relationship between Campaign and Call, but still keeping the relationship between a user and a call. How to do that?